# How do you block some REST methods with Spring Data Rest?

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

According to the docs here

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.http-methods.default-exposure

You can block certain REST methods by doing

```
ExposureConfiguration config = repositoryRestConfiguration.getExposureConfiguration();

config.forDomainType(User.class).disablePutForCreation(); 
config.withItemExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.PATCH));
```

but how do you block say "PATCH" for a sub resource?

So I can block

```
PATCH /api/users/1
```

but how to block

```
PATCH /api/users/1/tag
```

Answer (score 0):

```
config.withAssociationExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.PATCH));
```

To be precise:

```
config.forDomainType(User.class).withAssociationExposure((metadata, httpMethods) -> httpMethods.disable(HttpMethod.PATCH));
```